# Change ownership of file which is target a parentId, also ends up in root (2 parents in file)

Tags: google-drive-api

I have made a way to transfer file ownership within the domain, from admin user to destinationUser. This works expect that I have a issue with the **parents being added to the file when the permission is changed**.

**The Admin user are performing the sequence in this order:**

1. uploadFile - To the destinationUser's folder (which is shared to the admin to write in)
2. Insert permission (to the destinationUser as a user and have ownership of the file) (see code below).
3. Remove permission for the Admin user (this to only make the destinationUser to be the only owner of the file)

**The problem is in step 2**:

When the permission is shanged to the destinationUser, the file's parents are changed.
There now exist 2 parents, one of the destination Folder, but now also in Root (isRoot=true). The issue is that I didn't request it to be in root and I see this as a bug actually.

Even if I add a extra step after step 2, to update the parents to remove the "root" parent, this is not shown on the file. I guess due to that the admin now isn't owner of the file.

Are there any why to solve this issue, since the file shouldn't be both in the folder and root. Other sequence, or maybe file a bug-report on Google Drive API ??

```
            var service = new DriveService(CreateAuthenticator());
            var newPermission = new Permission();
            newPermission.Value = user.email;
            newPermission.Type = "user";
            newPermission.Role = "owner";
            try
            {
                return service.Permissions.Insert(newPermission, fileId).Fetch();
            }
            catch (Exception e).....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to go to Domain-Wide approach instead to remove this. Since I couldn't find any other solution.

Also Domain-Wide solution was better en cleaner when it eventually worked.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation